# Unable to uninstall certain applications and it throws an error "Could not open INSTALL.LOG file"

Tags: windows, uninstallation

Whenever I try to uninstall certain applications I get an error `Could not open INSTALL.LOG file` and then just prevents the application from getting uninstalled. I had faced this issue several times.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [The _khAttAm_ blog](https://www.khattam.info/could-not-open-installlog-file-problem-solved-2009-04-21.html) . Screenshot of the page placed at the bottom.

The solution is to go to the application's install location, find installer.log file in it and place it somewhere else. So that when the uninstaller runs, it will not find it and will ask you to select the file from a location. Now, select the file from where you have newly placed it. Now continue with uninstallation.

Done! Uninstallation completed!

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. In my case I could not find ANY `install.log` file on my system. I think the problem was that I installed an old driver and the installation never really worked from the beginning so an `install.log` file was never created. So what do I do now??

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me.  Needed to uninstall both utilities, Eusing Registry Cleaner and Eusing Cleaner, because they don't behave well in my Windows 10.  Disappointed that "Unwise" uninstallers didn't work, because I've never had a single problem with Eusing before.

Each program had a folder in the Program(x86) folder, and each folder had an Install.log file, in addition to the .exe file and the Unwise.exe file.

For each program, one at a time, I moved the Install.log file to the Desktop.  Then I ran the Unwise app again, and then it ran, finally.  In the process, it couldn't find the Install.log file, and it asked for the Install.log file to be clicked on.  So I clicked on it, and then the uninstallation completed.

Then I did the same thing with the other program.